# jquery set ul and li elements undesired styles being added

Tags: jquery

Thanks in advance for your help with my issue.

I have the following html...

```
<div id="mt-news" class="mt-news">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I am doing ajax calls using jquery. After each Ajax call I want to set and overwrite the content of the ul.

I have tried to do this using ...

```
$('#mt-news ul').html('<li><a class="red" href="#" target="_self">Context x</a></li>');
```

That seems to work ok however I always end up with...

```
<div id="mt-news" class="mt-news" style="width: 1030px;">
   <ul style="width: 0px;">
      <li class="" style="opacity: 1;">
        <a class="red" target="_self" href="#">Context x</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What I don't understand is why am I getting ul style="width: 0px;" and also li style="opacity: 1;". I am not specifying these styles?

thanks a lot

Comment: Something is clearly setting the styles for those elements, and it's not external stylesheets. You probably have more code that you're not showing us.

Comment: you can remove the style from them yourself $('#mt-news ul, #mt-news li').removeAttr('style');

Comment: thank you. I did the remove and it has got rid of my issue. A quick hack is what we all need sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think any issue with your dynamically generated code..i have shown dynamically generated code using alert and it looks fine as below

```
 $('#mt-news ul').html('<li><a class="red" href="#" target="_self">Context x</a></li>');
alert($('#mt-news').html());
```

fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/22/